# How do I identify a star in general?

Tags: star, identify-this-object

I recently asked quite a few [identify-this-object](/questions/tagged/identify-this-object) questions, and I think maybe this post can serve as a canonical for how to find a star in general?

Note that the pictures that you want to find the star from are **real photos**, like this photo from [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50553/what-is-the-bright-orange-star):

[image]

Related: [How to identify stars in photographs?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/how-to-identify-stars-in-photographs)

Note that I view "photos" as pictures taken by **telescopes** in this question, e.g. the Hubble Telescope or the James Webb Space Telescope.

Answer (score 2):

Find the area containing the object in [Aladin](https://aladin.cds.unistra.fr/AladinLite/).

It will look like a hazy version of the JWST or Hubble image.  Turn on the Simbad, Gaia, or 2MASS overlays. Use the overlays to find the identifier for the object. When you have the identifier of the object you can move to [Simbad](http://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/) to find more details.

It can sometimes help to use different surveys, but many of the higher Energy surveys are too low resolution to identify small objects, and work better over large areas.

In the case of this object, the problem is that the Tarantula nebula is so bright in visible light that it over exposes the whole region and you can see anything in the usual DSS2 survey. However in the longer wavelength 2Mass survey the inner part of the nebula is visible and the same star can be found.

[image]

Comment: Also [astrometry.net](https://nova.astrometry.net/) can be used to identify stars in images.